# Is there an antipattern to describe this method of coding?

Tags: design-patterns, anti-patterns

I have a codebase where the programmer tended to wrap things up in areas that don't make sense.  For example, given an Error log we have you can log via

```
ErrorLog.Log(ex, "friendly message");
```

He added various other means to accomplish the exact same task.  E.G.

```
SomeClass.Log(ex, "friendly message");
```

Which simply turns around and calls the first method.  This adds levels of complexity with no added benefit.  Is there an anti-pattern to describe this?

Comment: "Bad coding" covers it ;)

Comment: Is Log pure virtual? I have seen it where a print method is called on a class by operator<< to output the properties of a class, but never called Class.print(), rather print() was called within the operator<<.

Comment: Depends. Is it a wrapper for a logging library? If there ever was the chance it could be swapped this actually is a good practice...

Comment: I don't know an official name for it, but this deserves to be a recognized antipattern, since I know programmers who do the same... create layer after layer of pointless wrappers. Maybe "wrapper onion" would be a good fit?

Comment: Maybe [baklava code](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2009/07/27/baklav-code/)?

Comment: @lortabac: The problem with "baklava code" is that it acually sounds good and tasty, and therefore desirable.

Comment: Hmm. In black-and-white smalltalk, the definition of the `hilight` method was `self invert`. But that is a renaming for semantics on the same object. `my.log` => `other.log` is just a waste.

Comment: What does this programmer say when you add them why are they adding these methods? Understanding their reasoning should make it easier to educate them.

Comment: @Keith - He quit.  He was a cowboy who took off and did what cowboys do.  We looked at his code once in a while, but it was so overly complex we didn't even know where to start.  Now I'm going in and cleaning up the mess he left.

Comment: Sounds like a level of [indirection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GRASP_(object-oriented_design)#Indirection), which can be good when you want to avoid coupling between two classes, as @Rig pointed out. Perhaps it was just a coder suffering from [patternitis](http://www.samuelfolkes.com/of-design-patterns-and-patternitis/) - simply trying some pattern to solve a problem that's not there, violating KISS.

Comment: I think we're seeing a future submission to [TheDailyWTF](http://thedailywtf.com/)

Comment: Can you post a snippet of what SomeClass.log does? Is it passing something like a class name or state to the logger?

Comment: There can be arguments in favour of this. E.g. here's "Uncle Bob" (Robert Martin) [arguing in favour](https://sites.google.com/site/unclebobconsultingllc/blogs-by-robert-martin/dependency-injection-inversion) of centralising dependencies in a limited number of modules, rather than scattering them through the code.

Comment: Is SomeClass a logging decorator? Is it anchoring the functionality to an interface, or providing a common implementation for a inheritance chain? Does it provide a useful seam to facilitate testing? I.e. does it provide any additional value whatsoever over just calling ErrorLog.Log() directly? If it doesn't add any value, then its just a target for a refactor. If it does provide some value then its a judgement call if it provides _enough_ value to justify its existence.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

It is only worthwhile to call some bad coding habit an Antipattern if it is reasonably widespread.

The rest we just call "rubbish code" ...

---

If I was to suggest a name for this particular bad habit, it would be "Obsessive Abstraction Disorder" :-)

Comment: I've always used "Indirection Hell".

Answer (score 28):

No, it's not a anti pattern but I would raise the following issues.

**Violation of Single Responsibility Princple**

SRP says that a class should have one reason to change. Adding a logger method means that the class also have to change if the logging logic should be changed.

**Violation of a `is-a` relationship**

Base classes are not toolboxes where you can add several convenience methods.

Doing so effectively couples all inherited classes to the implementations that the base class has.

Compare that with composition.

Comment: "Single Responsibility issue"? SRP? Perhaps you meant to write Single Responsibility Principle? Just connecting the two here. :)

Answer (score 8):

Not that this makes it acceptable but this could just be an unfinished refactoring.  Maybe the SomeClass.log() had it's own logic an was implemented first.  And later they realized that they should be using ErrorLog.Log().  So rather than change 100 places where SomeClass.Log() is called, they just delegated to the ErrorLog.Log().  Personally I would change all the references to ErrorLog.Log() or at least comment SomeClass.log() to say why it delegates the way it does.

Just something to consider.

Answer (score 7):

The term "Lasagna Code" comes to my mind, though apparently it [means different things to different people](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1187995/335858). My interpretation has always been "layered for the sake of being layered".

Comment: I've also heard "Onion Code" to describe the same thing.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure to describe this as an offense to the single responsibility principle, because if there is a change to the ErrorLog method signature (the method that is called by SomeClass), every client code that calls this method will fail.

There is obviously a way to use inheritance (or making classes that needs logging implementing a logging interface) there.

Comment: Still bad practice because: 1) it's unlikely to change 2) if it does change, they can just build a wrapper class with the same name and change the imports.

Comment: +1. And here's "Uncle Bob" (Robert Martin) [arguing in favour](https://sites.google.com/site/unclebobconsultingllc/blogs-by-robert-martin/dependency-injection-inversion) of centralising dependencies in a limited number of modules, rather than scattering them through the code.

Answer (score 3):

Or we could look at this as a "teachable moment" :)

Your developer may be halfway to a good idea.  Suppose you want to have the requirement that all of your business objects are capable of intelligent logging.  You might define:

```
   public interface IBusinessObjectLogger
   {
       void Log(Exception ex, string logMessage)
   }
```

Now internal to your objects you can use the ErrorLog object to actually do the logging while SomeClass code adds object specific value to the log message.  You can then further extend your logging APIs to implement file based, db based or message based logging functionality without touching you business objects.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure this is automatically evil.

If you're calling SomeClass.Log it most certainly is evil but if Log is only being used from WITHIN SomeClass it's cutting down the coupling and I would call it acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually pretty common in certain coding styles, and the basics of the line of thought are not, in themselves, an anti-pattern.

It's very probably the result of someone coding by necessity without knowledge of the wider codebase: "OK, this code needs to log an error, but that function is not the code's primary purpose. Therefore, I need a method/class that will do that for me". That's a good way of thinking; but, without knowing ErrorLog existed, they created SomeClass. They then found ErrorLog at some later point, and rather than replace all usages of the method they'd put in, they made their method call ErrorLog. *That* is where this becomes a problem.

Answer (score 2):

**Accidental complexity** is complexity that arises in computer programs or their development process which is non-essential to the problem to be solved. While essential complexity is inherent and unavoidable, accidental complexity is caused by the approach chosen to solve the problem.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accidental_complexity

Answer (score 1):

It may be an abuse/misunderstanding of the [Facade Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern). I have seen similar things in a codebase I've worked with. The developers went through a phase when they were crazy about design patterns without understanding the overarching principles of OO design.

A misuse of the Facade pattern results in a blurring of the levels of abstraction across the layers of the application.

Answer (score 1):

What this programmer is doing is wrapping some code, so that it does not have a direct dependency on the logging module. Without more specific information, it's not possible to give a more specific pattern. (That these wrappers are not useful is your opinion which is impossible to agree or disagree with without much more information.)

Patterns that this may fall under are *Proxy*, *Delegate*, *Decorator*, *Composite* or some such which have to do with wrapping, hiding or distributing calls.  It may one of such things in an incomplete state of development.

Answer (score 0):

I could imagine it to be cultural difference. Maybe there is a good reason for having duplicate functionality in this particular code base. I could image ease of writing to be such a reason. The Python programmer in me would still say it is bad, since "[There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)", but some Perl guys might be accustomed to the fact that "[There's more than one way to do it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There%27s_more_than_one_way_to_do_it)".

Comment: Ease of *initial* writing is not a good reason for duplication. Bad code might be easier to write the first time around, but that does not make it easier to write code in the long-run. What does the new guy coming in do with the duplicated functionality? Which method does he call? He wastes time looking them up and reading them, only to find they do the same thing.

Comment: Maybe this code was originally meant as a prototype that then got (ab)used as an increment. In that case, optimizing for initial writing would have been valid, I think.